# Displaying Drawable in multiple EditText fields

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-edittext

I am trying to create the Registration page for my app and I am not able to display "a tick mark" drawable in all the edittext fields which have been filled correctly. Currently, the drawable is only displayed in the last ConfirmPassword EditText, and not the others even though they basically have the same code. Here's my XML file -

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/LoginActivityStyle"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="48dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:scaleX="2.7"
        android:scaleY="2.7"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_interact_logo" />

    <!--  Name Label -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/register_first_name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:hint="First Name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/register_last_name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:hint="Last Name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Email Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/register_email_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Password Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/register_password_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/register_confirm_password_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Signup Button -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/register_signup_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Create Account"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my activity's code-

```
    public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";
    private Button mSignUpButton;
    private TextView mLoginLinkTextView;
    private EditText mEmailEditText, mFirstNameEditText, mLastNameEditText, 
    mPasswordEditText, mConfirmPasswordEditText;
    private Drawable mCorrectDrawable;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mFirstNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.register_first_name_edit_text);
    mLastNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.register_last_name_edit_text);
    mEmailEditText = findViewById(R.id.register_email_edit_text);
    mLoginLinkTextView = findViewById(R.id.register_login_text_view);
    mCorrectDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_correct, null);
    mCorrectDrawable.setBounds(0,0, mCorrectDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), mCorrectDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    mCorrectDrawable.setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen, null));

    mEmailEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);
    mFirstNameEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);
    mLastNameEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);
    mPasswordEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0); 
    mEmailEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if(validateEmail()){
                mEmailEditText.setError(null);
                mEmailEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, mCorrectDrawable, null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
    mFirstNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if(validateFirstName()){
                mFirstNameEditText.setError(null);
                mFirstNameEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, mCorrectDrawable2, null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
    mLastNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (validateLastName()){
                mLastNameEditText.setError(null);
                mLastNameEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, mCorrectDrawable3, null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

public boolean validateFirstName(){
    boolean valid = true;
    String first_name = mFirstNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (first_name.isEmpty() || first_name.length() < 3) {
        mFirstNameEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);
        mFirstNameEditText.setError("Enter at least 3 characters");
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

public boolean validateLastName(){
    boolean valid = true;
    String last_name = mLastNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (last_name.isEmpty() || last_name.length() < 3) {
        mLastNameEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);
        mLastNameEditText.setError("Enter at least 3 characters");
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

public boolean validateEmail(){
    boolean valid = true;
    String email = mEmailEditText.getText().toString();
    if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        mEmailEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);
        mEmailEditText.setError("Enter a valid email address");
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

}

Please ignore the login, signup, etc. The backend is still not set-up. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT 1** - Firstly, sorry for not commenting the code. Secondly, I have finally found out what was causing the issue. The drawables weren't displaying because of the EditText.setError() statements. I stopped using those and used this instead to set the error message -

```
    myEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);    //Remove all drawables from the edittext field
    myInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
    myInputLayout.setError("Passwords do not match");
```

Here, the InputLayout is the one associated with that particular EditText field. Finally, to show the drawable -

```
    myInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);                    
    myEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, mCorrectDrawable, null);
```

**EDIT 2** - Here is what the page looks like - [Registration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiKqt.jpg)
**NOTE** I have also edited the code so that only relevant code is visible. Sorry for the poor editing.

Comment: There's a lot involved here.  Is it possible to make it more [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: can u share the design

Comment: A true Klingon warrior does not comment his code. Qapla'